# Input fields become unusable upon stacking in bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

[image]I am designing a view like this:

```
     @for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
     <div class="col-xs-12">
             <label class="control-label">Home</label>
             <select  class="form-control" name="homeTeam" >
                  <option value="1">Arsenal</option>
                  <option value="2">Chelsea</option>
                  <option value="3">Man Utd</option>

             </select>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12">
             <label class="control-label">Away</label>
             <select  class="form-control" name="awayTeam" >
                  <option value="1">Arsenal</option>
                  <option value="2">Chelsea</option>
                  <option value="3">Man Utd</option>

             </select>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12">
              <label class="control-label">Kick-Off</label>
              <input class="form-control form_datetime col-xs-12" size="16" type="text" value="" readonly>
     </div>
   @endfor
```

When I test this on normal display with sufficient width, it works ok. But when I reduce the size of the browser to match the col-xs range the input fields do stack up but become unclickable.

I am not sure why this is happening and whats the solution, tried different things nothing worked.

Comment: You code is working ok http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9397/

Comment: Gorostas : I have put it in loop, so this markup will get repeated 10 times lets say then there is a issue.

Comment: Loop is not a problem http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9398/ you have some other css thta is a problem, please check firebug or inspect element on your page

Comment: See this works fine when it is on full width view e.g 1000px or so..but when I reduce the width of the browser...its gets stack up all right...but everything is unclickable

Comment: Here is another example http://www.bootply.com/zSf3siv0Et, here you can use it in full screen, and resize it :)

Comment: the problem is not in this part of the code, the problem is maybe in your layout, or some before elements

Comment: Seriously..I tried ur bootply link its working flawless there..yes, I agree that this must be because of some parent element...because I am adding this markup via AJAX call to an element. Any idea, generally what causes this...i think its overlapping of divs or something.

Comment: Having tough time finding it..thank you for your help anyway. Appreciate it!